# Create cumulative unique arrays in Kusto

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer

I am struggling to write a KQL for the following scenario - I have a number of servers (reasonably small, <1000) and at any timestep a small subset (<10) of servers might experience an issue. I know which servers experienced issue at which timestamp but need to create an ever-growing array representing unique servers that have experienced issue up until and including a given timestamp.

I constructed the below KQL query but it only works for first two rows and fails for the third and any subsequent one. I would much appreciate any help.

```
range Time from 1 to 100 step 1
| extend ServerIds=array_sort_asc(pack_array(rand(100), rand(100),
    rand(100), rand(100), rand(100), rand(100),
    rand(100), rand(100), rand(100), rand(100)))
| extend ServerIds=array_slice(ServerIds, 0, toint(rand(10)))
//The above code generates 100 random arrays of length 1 to 10.
| sort by Time asc
| extend CumulativeUniqueServerIds=array_sort_asc(set_union(ServerIds, prev(ServerIds)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [scan-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scan-operator)

```
range Time from 1 to 100 step 1
| extend ServerIds=array_sort_asc(pack_array(rand(100), rand(100),
    rand(100), rand(100), rand(100), rand(100),
    rand(100), rand(100), rand(100), rand(100)))
| extend ServerIds=array_slice(ServerIds, 0, toint(rand(10)))
//The above code generates 100 random arrays of length 1 to 10.
| sort by Time asc
| scan declare (CumulativeUniqueServerIds:dynamic=dynamic([])) with (
  step s1: true => CumulativeUniqueServerIds = array_sort_asc(set_union(s1.CumulativeUniqueServerIds,ServerIds));
)
```